# how to find all occurrence with indexes of string in an ArrayList java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Having an ArrayList with data like below. My requirement is to find all the indexes where length of data is 4.

```
values.add("1000");
values.add("10001111");
values.add("45678901");
values.add("1111");
values.add("22222222");
values.add("2222");
values.add("33333333");
```

Comment: Where is the code that is trying to achieve that?

Comment: If you show minimal effort or tell us what went wrong, we can help you find a solution. This seems like homework and we won´t do it for you.

Comment: Read the following help topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You need to :

- iterate over the values
- check the length
- keep the index if condition passed

---

1. [***`Workable demo`***](https://ideone.com/3tfn7H) **:** Using `Streams` you can inline the solution to obtain a `List` or a `int[]`

   ```
   List<Integer> indexes = values.stream().filter(s -> s.length() == 4)
                                          .map(values::indexOf)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

   int[] indexesArray = values.stream().filter(s -> s.length() == 4)
                                       .mapToInt(values::indexOf)
                                       .toArray();
   ```
2. [***`Workable demo`***](https://ideone.com/ECLWl4) **:** Using a classic `for loop`

   ```
   List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
       if(values.get(i).length() == 4){
           indexes.add(i);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `IntStream` of indices:

```
IntStream allIndices = IntStream.range(0, values.size());
```

Which you then can filter, by the condition you provided:

```
IntStream filteredIndices = allIndices.filter(i -> values.get(i).length() == 4);
```

Finally you can transform those indices into any dataStructure you like.

An array:

```
int[] indices = filteredIndices.toArray();
```

Or a List

```
List<Integer> indices = filteredIndices.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

As one statement:

```
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, values.size())
    .filter(i -> values.get(i).length() == 4)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: This one is quick and sort. Thanks @Lino.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the matching values and its indices/indexes in a `Map<Integer, String>` when you iterate over the `values` and output the content of that `Map` afterwards:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        values.add("1000");
        values.add("10001111");
        values.add("45678901");
        values.add("1111");
        values.add("22222222");
        values.add("2222");
        values.add("33333333");

        // create a storage structure for index and value
        Map<Integer, String> valuesWithLengthFour = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        // iterate over your list in order to get all the matching values and indexes
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            String value = values.get(i);
            if (value.length() == 4) {
                valuesWithLengthFour.put(i, value);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The following matching values were found in \"values\":");

        // print out the content of the storage structure
        for (int key : valuesWithLengthFour.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Index: " + key + ", Value: " + valuesWithLengthFour.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

There are different ways to achieve this... For a one liner, try out the code @Lino stated in one of the comments below your question.